# ¿Por qué se "borra" Python.exe al ejecutar Python desde Git Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

Estoy aprendiendo Python y en las clases piden utilizarlo desde Git Bash. También, descargué Python con Anaconda. He instalado primero Git y luego Anaconda.

El comando que utilizo desde Git Bash es:

```
> D:/Anaconda3/python
```

y también he intentado:

```
> python
```

Justo luego de ejecutar el comando, el ejecutable de Python dentro del directorio de Anaconda pasa de 90 KB a 0 KB.

Ambos, Anaconda y Git están instalados directamente en el disco D, en ningún sub folder ni nada por el estilo. Si abro directamente **Anaconda Prompt** y coloco `python` en este caso sí se ejecuta. El problema es que necesito que se ejecute el interpretador desde Git Bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me temo que la fuente de tus problemas es el `>` que pones delante del comando. Quizás has copiado el carácter de algunos apuntes o tutorial, pero ese carácter no debe ser copiado, sino que representa al *prompt*, es decir, lo que tu operativo imprime cuando estás en la terminal esperando a que escribas algo. En una interfaz de comandos Windows, el prompt suele ser el símbolo `>`, mientras que en unix (y en GitBash) suele ser el símbolo `$`.

En cualquier caso, no debes teclear ese símbolo delante de tus comandos. Cuando el usuario pone ese símbolo como parte de un comando, está pidiendo al intérprete de comandos que redirija la salida del comando a un fichero. Por ejemplo:

```
dir > resultado
```

ejecutará el comando `dir` y, en lugar de mostrar el resultado por pantalla, lo enviará a un fichero llamado `resultado`. Si ese fichero ya existiera lo borraría antes.

Cuando tú pones:

```
> python
```

Estás ejecutando "nada" (no hay comando delante del `>`) y enviando la salida a un fichero llamado `python`. No es extraño que el fichero tenga 0 bytes después, ya que el comando vacío no ha producido ningún texto.

Al margen de ese problema, algunos detalles más:

- Cuando estás dentro de GitBash el intérprete de comandos no es el habitual `cmd` de Windows, sino `bash`, uno más habitual en Linux. En general los comandos que tienes en ese shell no son los mismos que en Windows. Por ejemplo, en lugar de `dir` debes usar `ls` (aunque GitBash soporta también `dir`), en lugar de `ren` debes usar `mv` (para renombrar ficheros), etc.
- Ya que no estás en un intérprete "normal" de comandos de Windows, las rutas a los archivos tampoco son normales. Usan la barra `/` en lugar de la barra `\` para separar carpetas, y para refererirte a un disco, en lugar de `C:\` debes usar `/c/`.

Según lo anterior, para lanzar python deberías poner tras el prompt el comando siguiente (en este ejemplo, `$` es el prompt que te muestra GitBash, no es parte del comando a teclear):

```
$ /d/Anaconda3/python
```

Por alguna razón que no tengo clara, si lanzas python de este modo (sin pasarle el nombre del programa `.py` que debería ejecutar), en lugar de entrar al intérprete interactivo, se queda como colgado. Alguna interacción rara con GitBash. Para evitarlo pon la opción `-i`:

```
$ /d/Anaconda3/python -i
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Finalmente, si no quieres tener que poner la ruta completa cada vez que invocas Python, puedes añadir esa ruta al `PATH` de GitBash:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/d/Anaconda3
$ python -i
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Esta asignación del PATH se pierde cuando cierres esta terminal, y deberás volver a hacerla cuando abras una nueva. Si quieres que la definición se ejecute automáticamente en todas las terminales GitBash que abras, puedes crear un fichero en tu carpeta de usuario que se llame `.profile` y que contenga la línea:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/d/Anaconda3
```

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que el usuario ha aceptado la respuesta, deduzco que acerté con la explicación. Me pregunto el por qué del voto negativo.

Comment: Cuando se usa el usuario root el prompt suele ser `#`. Pero vaya, va a gustos porque es configurable.

Comment: Sobre la explicación: `X > fichero` lo que hace es vaciar el fichero antes de nada y luego rellenarlo con lo que venga de `X` que en este caso no es nada. Pero es importante destacar que lo primero es el vaciado, de ahí que `cat fichero > fichero` lo deje vacío.